# Is there a way to replace string in URL that precedes a known string?

Tags: c#, string, url, replace

I am trying to find a way to replace an arbitrary number in an URL that is followed by a known element.

For example, finding "20200116141908/smaller_square" in the original where "/smaller-square" is always following the arbitrary number is arbitrary, and replace both with "/large", for the result below:

**ORIGINAL**:

```
https://www.artforhire.com/p/assets/images/images/023/441/726/20200116141908/smaller_square/bear.jpg
                                                             ^------------REPLACE---------^
```

**Intended result**:

```
https://www.artforhire.com/p/assets/images/images/023/441/726/large/bear.jpg
```

Comment: `string result = url.Replace(stringToReplace, "/large");`?

Comment: Yes, there is a way.

Comment: @DaggeJ the issue with a standard `String.Replace` is that the number is arbitrary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Regex:

```
string newUrl = Regex.Replace(originalUrl, @"\d+\/smaller_square", "large");
```

`\d+` matches one or more digits.

If there are always 14 digits then you can use `\d{14}` instead.

Comment: Did you test this before posting? Your output is `https://www.artforhire.com/p/assets/images/images/023/441/726/20200116141908/smaller_square/bear.jpg`.

Comment: This is fantastic - I am awful at REGEX, but this works but you have to change "smaller-square", to "smaller_square" :)  Thank you so much!!

Comment: @ChrisL - No, it doesn't. It's still faulty after that.

Comment: It's still wrong - `https://www.artforhire.com/p/assets/images/images/023/441/726//large/bear.jpg`.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes you are right, the slashes have now been sorted.

Comment: Awesome. I do appreciate an answer that works and works well. :-)

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, they are more helpful than answers that don't work ;-).

Comment: @ChrisL I corrected as per that comment, can you try again?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay - I'd recommend that you include a full set of code in your answers. Enough for someone to copy, paste, and test. I tend to feel naked if my answers don't meet that level of detail.